# Ouath2 401 Error: The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported parameter value, or is otherwise malformed

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, xmlhttprequest

First, thank you for taking the time to review this and potentially help out! Second, I have a situation involving an authentication scenario between two apps: (1) a Raspberry Pi Node app using serverside XHR and (2) Ruby API with Oauth 2.0.

There have been some difficulties with the Ruby endpoints but they seem to have been stabilized. Enough so that we can authenticate correctly through POSTMAN and (hopefully) from our Raspberry Pi.

In attempting that, I'm getting the following exception using my custom logger:

```
NEW EXCEPTION - Thu Dec 14 2017 00:23:20 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) - Failed RESTful Async POST failed: 4 401 {"UNSENT":0,"OPENED":1,"HEADERS_RECEIVED":2,"LOADING":3,"DONE":4,"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":\"invalid_request\",\"error_description\":\"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported parameter value, or is otherwise malformed.\"}","responseXML":"","status":401,"statusText":null,"withCredentials":true}!
```

Here's the data sent over (redacted):

```
NEW ENTRY - Thu Dec 14 2017 00:23:19 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) - REST POST for: http://cms.....ca/oauth/token with body: {"client_id":"...9","client_secret":"......","audience":"....ca","scope":"client admin","grant_type":"password","username":"admin@....ca","password":"qqqqqqq"}
```

The below POSTMAN POST does work (redacted):

[image]

POST is made Pi-side through:

```
headerAsyncPost: (url, data, headerKey, headerValue) => {
        if (c.jobLogging()) l.log(`REST POST for ${url} with body: ${JSON.stringify(data)} ${headerKey} ${headerValue}`, 1);
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            try {
                let r = new XMLHttpRequest();
                s.xhrReady(url, r, 'Success', 'RESTful Async POST failed', res, rej);
                r.open("POST", url, true);
                r.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
                r.setRequestHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
                r.send(JSON.stringify(data));
            } catch (ex) {
                l.err(`Exception ${ex}`);
            }
        });
    },
```

I don't believe this is my code (since it works on other sites for Oauth2 and is currently working to authenticate elsewhere) but I'd appreciate any advice in helping to clear up whether this is Pi-side or Ruby-side/any fixes I can make. Honestly, I'd rather use a more lightweight and sophisticated implementation Ruby-side. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved - the endpoint cannot support JSON POST with Body but only parameters appended to URL:

```
   testPost: (url, params, headerKey, headerValue) => {
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            try {
                let r = new XMLHttpRequest();

                for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(params).length; i++) {
                    if (i === 0) url += `?`;
                    url += `${Object.keys(params)[i]}=${params[Object.keys(params)[i]]}`;
                    if (i < Object.keys(params).length - 1) url += `&`;
                }
                l.log(`${url}`, 1);
                s.xhrReady(url, r, 'Success', 'RESTful Async TestPOST failed', res, rej);
                r.open("POST", url, true);
                r.setRequestHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
                r.send();
            } catch (ex) {
                l.err(`Exception ${ex}`);
            }
        })
    },
```